# Add few lines of code in php

Tags: php, mysql, server, phpmyadmin

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC7Wy.png)
I have written a PHP program which take user new and old password my code is running well but now I have to few lines of code in my PHP program.
This is my code of PHP which I written and I want to add few lines of code in it but when I write new code in it works but it shows new errors, that code which I have to written is warning to user that user "new password should be different with old password". This code warns user when user enter on submit button of new password same as old password webpage.

This is my PHP program:

```
<?php 
session_start();

// if ($_SESSION['user_name'] != "") 
// {
//     header("location:account.php");
// }

include('connection.php'); 

// header("Refresh: 20; URL=welcome.php");
// header("Refresh: 20; URL=http://www.stackoverflow.com/");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $old_password = $_POST['old_password'];
    $new_password = $_POST['new_password'];

    $query = $con->prepare("select password from tbl_users WHERE id = :user_id");
    $query->bindParam(':user_id', $_SESSION['id']); 
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $query->execute();
    $fetch = $query->fetch();

    $old_pass = $fetch['password']; 


    if($old_password == $old_pass){
        $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE tbl_users SET password = (:pass) WHERE id = :user_id");
        $stmt->bindParam(':pass', $new_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);       
        $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $_SESSION['id']);    
        // $stmt->execute(); 

        $stmt->execute();
        header("location:account.php");
    }
    else
    { 
        echo "<script>alert('Wrong password! Enter your valid old password')</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>project</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="registration.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header><h1>Change Password</h1></header>
<form method="post" action="renew.php">
<br />
<input type="password" id="pwd2" placeholder="Enter your old password" name="old_password" required />
<br />


<input type="password" id="pwd1" placeholder="Enter your new password" name="new_password" required />
<center>
<!-- <div class="form-group"> -->
      <div id="setPasswordMessage" style="display: none;"></div>
<!-- </div> -->
</center>
<br />

<div class="buttons">
<input type="submit" disabled="submit" class="btn"  name="submit" value="Save">
</div>
<br />
</form>
<footer><h3>Copyright &copy; vu.edu.pk (S1701F607E)</h3></footer>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  var pwd1    = $('#pwd1'); //id of first password field
  var pwd2    = $('#pwd2'); //id of second password field
  var pwdIdSet  = $('#setPasswordMessage'); //id of indicator element

  setCheckPasswordStrength(pwd1,pwd2,pwdIdSet); //call password check function

});

function setCheckPasswordStrength(pwd1, pwd2, pwdIdSet)
{
  /*=========== Start: Set Password Cretria Regular Expression ===================*/

  //Password must contain 5 or more characters
  var lowPassword = /(?=.{5,}).*/;  

  //Password must contain at least one digit and lower case letters .
  var mediumPassword = /^(?=\S*?[a-z])(?=\S*?[0-9])\S{5,}$/;

  //Password must contain at least one digit, one upper case letter and one lower case letter.
  var averagePassword = /^(?=\S*?[A-Z])(?=\S*?[a-z])(?=\S*?[0-9])\S{5,}$/; 

  //Password must contain at least one digit, one upper case letter and one lower case letter.
  var strongPassword = /^(?=\S*?[A-Z])(?=\S*?[a-z])(?=\S*?[0-9])(?=\S*?[^\w\*])\S{5,}$/; 

  /*=========== End: Set Password Cretria Regular Expression ===================*/

// test() method is used to test match in a string whether the value is matched in a string or not.

  $(pwd1).on('keyup', function(e) {
    var len = $('#pwd1').val().length;
    document.getElementById("setPasswordMessage").style.display="block";
    if(strongPassword.test(pwd1.val()))
    {
      pwdIdSet.removeClass().addClass('strongPassword').html("Strong! Please use this password!").css("display","block");
      $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
    } 
    else if(averagePassword.test(pwd1.val()))
    {
      pwdIdSet.removeClass().addClass('averagePassword').html("Average! Tips: Enter special characters to make even stronger").css("display","block");
      $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
    } 
    else if(mediumPassword.test(pwd1.val()))
    {
      pwdIdSet.removeClass().addClass('mediumPassword').html("Good! Tips: Enter uppercase letter to make strong").css("display","block");
      $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else if(lowPassword.test(pwd1.val()))
      {
      pwdIdSet.removeClass().addClass('stilllowPassword').html("Still Weak! Tips: Enter digits to make good password").css("display","block");
      $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
      }

      else if(len < 1)
      {
        pwdIdSet.removeClass('lowPassword');
        $('#setPasswordMessage').css("display","none");
        $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
      }

    else 
    {
      pwdIdSet.removeClass().addClass('lowPassword').html("Very Weak! Please use 5 or more chars password)").css("display","block");
      $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });

  // $(pwd2).on('keyup', function(e) {

  //  if(pwd1.val() !== pwd2.val()) 
  //  {
  //    pwdIdSet.removeClass().addClass('lowPassword').html("Passwords do not match!"); 
  //  }else{
  //    pwdIdSet.removeClass().addClass('goodpass').html("Passwords match!"); 
  //  }

  // });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have to add this code in PHP code but in which place and how.

```
if($old_password == $new_password)
{ 
  echo "<script>alert('New password should be different with old password')</script>";
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what's the error? What are you having difficulty with?

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't store plaintext passwords in the database, you should use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.

Comment: you talk like someone else wrote the above code

Comment: I am posting an image it my question please wait

Comment: Errors are Undefined variables: old_password in C:------------ on line 42, Undefined variables: new_password in C:------------ on line 42

Comment: The PHP code written by my friend because he knows MySQL and how to implement PHP and MySQL together.

Answer (score 0):

Put the check right before you do the query.

```
<?php 
session_start();

// if ($_SESSION['user_name'] != "") 
// {
//     header("location:account.php");
// }

include('connection.php'); 

// header("Refresh: 20; URL=welcome.php");
// header("Refresh: 20; URL=http://www.stackoverflow.com/");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $old_password = $_POST['old_password'];
    $new_password = $_POST['new_password'];

    if ($old_password == $new_password) {
        echo "<script>alert('New password should be different with old password')</script>";
    } else {
        $query = $con->prepare("select password from tbl_users WHERE id = :user_id");
        $query->bindParam(':user_id', $_SESSION['id']); 
        $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $query->execute();
        $fetch = $query->fetch();

        $old_pass = $fetch['password']; 


        if($old_password == $old_pass){
            $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE tbl_users SET password = (:pass) WHERE id = :user_id");
            $stmt->bindParam(':pass', $new_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);       
            $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $_SESSION['id']);    
            // $stmt->execute(); 

            $stmt->execute();
            header("location:account.php");
        }
        else
        { 
            echo "<script>alert('Wrong password! Enter your valid old password')</script>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks bro it works Thank you very much and God bless you

Answer (score 0):

PHP throws error if header is sent after any output. Thus, if you have any output before `header("location:account.php");`, an error will occur. Try setting new location via JS instead:

```
// header("location:account.php");
echo "<script>document.location.href = 'account.php';</script>";
```

the full code will look something like this:

```
if($old_password == $old_pass){
    if($old_password == $new_password)
    { 
      echo "<script>alert('New password should be different with old password')</script>";
    } else {
        $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE tbl_users SET password = (:pass) WHERE id = :user_id");
        $stmt->bindParam(':pass', $new_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);       
        $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $_SESSION['id']);    
        // $stmt->execute(); 

        $stmt->execute();
        // header("location:account.php");
        echo "<script>document.location.href = 'account.php';</script>";
    }
}
else....
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put this check after you set the variables `$old_password` and `$new_password` and before you execute any database queries (you don't want to execute these if old and new password are the same):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $old_password = $_POST['old_password'];
    $new_password = $_POST['new_password'];

    if($old_password == $new_password)
    { 
        echo "<script>alert('New password should be different with old password')</script>";
    }
    else
    {

        $query = $con->prepare("select password from tbl_users WHERE id = :user_id");
        $query->bindParam(':user_id', $_SESSION['id']); 
        $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $query->execute();
        $fetch = $query->fetch();

        $old_pass = $fetch['password']; 


        if($old_password == $old_pass){
            $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE tbl_users SET password = (:pass) WHERE id = :user_id");
            $stmt->bindParam(':pass', $new_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);       
            $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $_SESSION['id']);    
            // $stmt->execute(); 

            $stmt->execute();
            header("location:account.php");
        }
        else
        { 
            echo "<script>alert('Wrong password! Enter your valid old password')</script>";
        }
    }
}
```

And while it has nothing to do with coding, I just wanted to note that your error message is not correct English. Something is "different from" something else, not "different with". Use this:

> Your new password must be different from your old password